# Simplify a typical(?) conditional construct

Tags: logic, boolean-logic

I frequently saw (and sometimes written myself) constructs like:

```
if(A || B)
{
    var sharedValue = ...;
    if(A)
    {
      // do stuff with sharedValue
    }
    else
    {
      // do other stuff with sharedValue 
    }
}
```

Real example:

```cs
switch (e.Key)
{
   /* 
    * Don't mind the switch, since it can be simply converted into:
    * if(e.Key == Key.Left || e.Key == Key.Right) { ... }
    */
   case Key.Left: 
   case Key.Right:
       var container = containerFromData(data);
       if (e.Key == Key.Left)
       {
          this.TryNavigateBackward(container);
       }
       else
       {
          this.TryNavigateForward(container);
       }
}
```

I really *feel* like I'm missing something, so there must be a better (simpler, less verbose) way to describe that, but couldn't come up with an idea. This question maybe somewhat bound to the programming language one use (I'm currently in C#), but are there any constructs out there, being able to simplify the given example?

**Note:** I'm aware of the ternary conditional operator `a ? b : c`, but this (at least in C#) only works when retrieving values and putting them into variables. The example above wants to actually *do* different (maybe complex) things with a *shared* Value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since I don't see any other suggestions, I'll throw some out and see whether they're what you're looking for.

First, if OOP is on the table, inheritance can represent this sort of shared behavior. What you would do is encapsulate the shared, `A`-specific and `B`-specific behavior in classes `Shared`, `ASpecific` and `BSpecific`, where `ASpecific` and `BSpecific` inherit from `Shared`. Then, if either `A` or `B`, you spin up an instance of either `ASpecific` or `BSpecific`, respectively, and then treat it as an instance of `Shared`. If you have conditions `C`, `D`, etc. that don't use the shared thing, you'd have possibly another parent class called `Base` and you'd have `CBase`, `DBase` inheriting from `Base`, `Shared` inheriting from `Base`, and spin up an instance depending on the condition and treat the result as an instance of `Base`.

Second, you could use inversion of control by passing in A-specific and B-specific behaviors to a shared method when shared stuff is required. You could use OOP for this or pure functional programming. Going with the latter (since the former is similar to the above solution and maybe not as good), you'd have a `shared` function that takes  function `f` as an argument. The function `f` would have a signature that requires the shared object be passed in. Then, if `A`, call `shared` with a function (pointer or anonymous inline) that does the `A`-specific stuff to the shared object passed into it; otherwise, if `B`, call `shared` with a function that does the `B`-specific stuff to the shared object passed into it.

If all you really want to avoid is nesting, you could also bring the `if (A || B) { … }` stuff out and make it spin up shared which is declared but not instantiated in a higher scope; then, later, check `A` and `B` separately and know that in those cases `shared` will have the required setup from earlier.

Comment: Thanks for the great explanation, for me the first approach seems most suitable, I'm going to check that out. Thanks again.